Доступ к docker контейнеру по его сетевому адресу в Windows
уважаемое сообщество!
Программное окружение:

Windows 11
WSL2 + ubuntu 22.04 работающая под ней
Docker Desktop v4.28.0 - включена интеграция с WSL и дистрибутивом Ubuntu

Что делаю:
Запускаю docker-compose файл с нужными мне сервисами. Сеть - стандартная, по умолчанию это bridge. Сервисы поднимаются нормально, все работает. Сервисам выдаются адреса из подсети 172.19.0.0/16 (шлюз - 172.19.0.1)
Описание проблемы:
С хост машины (т.е. из под Windows) не запущенные контейнеры не видны по их сетевым адресами (видны только по 127.0.0.1 и тем портам, которые указаны к пробросу в docker-compose.yaml файле). При этом из под самих контейнеров хост машина прекрасно видна (например они взаимодействуют с СУБД на ней запущенной).
Вопрос: какие действия надо предпринять, что бы видеть контейнеры по их нормальным сетевым адресам с хост машины. Требуется это для удобства разработки, когда часть сервисов работает в докере, а тот что находится в разработке запущен в среде, п т.к. взаимодействие с сервисами ведется через Service Discovery то они в нем регистрируются под своими нормальными адресами и соответственно сообщаются всем другим.
